# Getting error Please provide valid credentials. OAuth oauth_problem="OST_OAUTH_PARAMETER_ABSENT_ERROR", realm="yahooapis.com"

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am working on " http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/ " site.
http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20social.profile%20where%20guid='ZGVG52ZDAYGCZRFF4VBA5L6ICY'

when i enter the executed string in the address bar

Please provide valid credentials. OAuth oauth_problem="OST_OAUTH_PARAMETER_ABSENT_ERROR", realm="yahooapis.com"   is cooured  i think authentication error is occure . But i couldnot understand where i set the authentication parameter with api ? in the url ? but how ?  Please help with an example code.

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. What is the second link for? What does "cooured" mean? What have you tried?

Answer (score 4):

I think you need to add Authorization header with requesting Uri as header. Some thing like this

```
        string headerString = "Authorization: OAuth realm=Your Oauth realm&" +
                            "oauth_timestamp= xxxxxxxx&oauth_nonce=your value&,"+
                            "oauth_version=1.0&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&"+
                                "oauth_consumer_key=your key&,oauth_token=your token&"+
                                    "oauth_signature=your signature";

        var req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("requsting uri");
        req.ContentType = "application/xml";
        req.Method = "POST";
        req.Headers.Add(headerString);

        HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
        var sr = new StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream());
        string response = sr.ReadToEnd().Trim();
```

Here i am assuming you are making a POST call.